# mod_rewrite is redirecting the browser instead of rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using the following mod_rewrite to redirect from the top directory of my site, to the subdirectory `shows/`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ shows [L]
```

The redirect is performing fine. However, the URL is *displaying* the redirect, which I believe it should not if you use mod_rewrite.

To clarify: A browser pointed towards `http://www.example.com/` is redirected to the subdirectory `shows/`. But the browser displays the redirect in the URL as `http://www.example.com/shows/`. Again, it is my understanding that by using mod-rewrite, you make the redirect invisible, so the user is not aware the redirect has taken place.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now see the problem. You are rewriting a URL from `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/shows`. Since `/shows` is a directory and not a file, Apache sends a *trailing slash* redirect after rewriting. Here is How you fix it:

```
RewriteRule ^$ shows/ [L]
# here -------------^
```

Note: since Apache might have sent a *301 Moved Permanently* header earlier, browsers will cache this response and it might show you wrong page/content even after you make changes to your .htaccess file. Clear browser cache often when you're testing.

Comment: Naaay that did not. It complete changed what was considered the root folder. All linked files on the page didn't link up. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: It works as expected on my system: `localhost/` showed content from `localhost/shows/` without a 301 redirect or change of address in the address bar. As for broken links: you should expect them and find a work around.

Comment: I didn't build the site, and everything is linked relative to the root, so changing what is considered the root would be a bit more work that I would do for a solution to this problem. I can live with seeing the directory that has been redirected to.

Comment: I actually notice that about the browser cache earlier with a different variant of my code. Anyway, is `RewriteRule ^$ shows/ [L]
# here -------------^` literally what I replace my code with? I've just never seen code like `# here -------------^` so I'm wondering if I'm suppose to replace that with some other code... sorry it's late.

Comment: Inside .htaccess and other apache configuration files, lines starting with a `#` are comments. You do not have to copy that line.

Comment: Ooooh I see! You're pointing me to the forward slash with an arrow! See, I knew I would get it. Ok, I'll test it out. I would feel mighty silly if that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same for a long time ago,so I decided to search on google and I found your question. I realised that there is something like two options "Redirect" and "Remapping". So I think here is the key to understand what you were asking. Basically, there are two options

redirection without change the url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/foo\.html$ /bar.html [PT]
```

& and redirection changing the url on the browser.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/foo\.html$ bar.html [R]
```

Anyway, take a look here 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html